Does the question "anything else I can do for you?" use correct word order?
I was playing Final Fantasy Tactics and saw such an order of question. Is this order legal or not?


Shopkeeper: Anything else I can do for you?

I have always thought that the only possible order, as for this question, looks like

Can I do something else for you?

I have always thought that the order should be like that
What / Who / Which / Whom / Where / ... + modal verb / do / did / have / has/ had + ...
I understand that this is merely game and these dialogues may be written by illeterate people, but nevertheless ...

There are many ways to skin a cat. And by the way, there's a typo in your question it should be illiterate two L's, two I's, two T's, and two E's.

This is normal colloquial English. It's actually short for "Is there anything else I can do for you?"

Yes, just like "Any dessert I can get you?," "Anything you don't see on the menu that you'd like?," or the always handy "Any other world problem you want me to solve today?"

Thank you very much.
